# C# Writing the line values of string arrays that match the line values of sorted double arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, double, console.writeline

In my program I sort a double array and then display it in the newly sorted order, however I also want to display the values that would be in the matching (post-sort) line in the other arrays, however when I use the code shown below I get the error "CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type double to int. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" - I understand why this is, as it is trying to convert the double array when all I really need it to do is access the integer used to keep track of the lines within it.

```
mySortDouble(array_D, array_D.Length-1);

for (int p = 0; p < array_D.Length; p++)
{
    Console.Write("{0}\t", stringArray1[array_D[p]]);
    Console.Write("{0}\t", stringArray2[array_D[p]]);
    Console.Write("{0}\t", stringArray3[array_D[p]]);
    Console.Write("{0}\t", array_D[p]); // the line values should match these
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

For example if the first element of array_D was 2.2 and the first element of stringArray1 was File1, then if 2.2 got sorted onto the third line, then the original matching value of stringArray1 should also be printed on the same line.

How can I access each line value of the sorted double array and use it to write the matching line value of the string arrays?

Comment: The error occurs because you are using a `double` (`array_D[p]`) as an index for the stringArrays.
Cast the index and see what happends: use `stringArray1[(int)array_D[p]]`

Comment: Can you give an example of what is in these arrays and what you expect to see in the `{0}` position when you write these?

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the string array at the same time as you sort the doubles to keep them in step, using [a special overload of `Array.Sort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h22cx4f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
double[] doubles = { 2, 6, 7, 8, 1, 0, 8, 9, 5, 4};
string[] strings = doubles.Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray();

Array.Sort(doubles, strings);

for (int i = 0; i < doubles.Length; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine(doubles[i] + ": " + strings[i]);
```

If you don't want to change the order of the items in the string array, you can instead create an array of indices and sort that along with the doubles. Then you can use the sorted indices to find the original strings for each sorted double, like so:

```
double[] doubles = { 2, 6, 7, 8, 1, 0, 8, 9, 5, 4};
string[] strings = doubles.Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray();
int[]    indices = Enumerable.Range(0, doubles.Length).ToArray();

Array.Sort(doubles, indices);

for (int i = 0; i < doubles.Length; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine(doubles[i] + ": " + strings[indices[i]]);
```

(These code samples just use the doubles converted to strings for the string values, for clarity.)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear on what you are trying to achieve. If you have multiples arrays like this:

```
double[] array_D; // array with the doubles to be sorted.
string[] stringArray1; // first array with elements lining up at the same index
string[] stringArray2; // second array lining up at the same index
string[] stringArray3; // third array lining up at the same index
```

That all have the same length, and where the index into the array gives the elements that belong together, i.e. `array_D[10]`, `stringArray1[10]`, `stringArray2[10]` and `stringArray3[10]` belong together.

Then, if you want to be able to keep track of this relationship after sorting the double array `array_D`, you will need an intermediate index that is sorted together with the array:

```
var indexArray = Enumerable.Range(0, array_D.Length).ToArray();
Array.Sort(array_D, indexArray);
```

Now you can do what you want like this:

```
for (int p = 0; p < array_D.Length; p++)
{
    Console.Write("{0}\t", stringArray1[indexArray[p]]);
    Console.Write("{0}\t", stringArray2[indexArray[p]]);
    Console.Write("{0}\t", stringArray3[indexArray[p]]);
    Console.Write("{0}\t", array_D[p]); // the line values should match these
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```